# Authenticated web/json requests

Tags: garmin

I need to do a basic authenticated web request but found out that even this does not work in Monkey C and Fenix 3 watch:

```
Comm.makeJsonRequest("http://username:password@somewebsite.com/somerestjsonservice, 
                     {}, {}, method(:onReceive));
```

As I get a 401 response code. BTW, the same code works fine in the simulator, but not on the watch (which is connected over Bluetooth to my phone and has net access).

Is there a better/different way?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with *makeWebRequest* instead of *makeJsonRequest*.